# Public to Public NAT/Routing

Tags: routing, nat

We have a set of web services available to our customers.  Many of our customers have firewall/proxy exceptions setup to our public IP address.  We need to expand and move to a new location.  Part of the move will be getting new IP addresses.  My question is this.  Can I setup either a router or firewall at the current location that will forward traffic from our old IP to our new IP without intervention by our customers?  My goal is to have our customers remain connected without modifying their firewall/proxy exception list.  Obviously I would update our DNS, but some customers whitelist specifically by IP so DNS doesn't come into play.

Comment: If you change your DNS, the customers who whitelist by IP will lose access anyway, won't they? (I mean, of course they're connecting by domain name so they can validate the SSL certificate, right?). I can think of a couple of workarounds, not sure I'd want to put any in production. (A site to site VPN, firewall does port forwarding over the VPN and does NAT so the return traffic comes back over the VPN).

Comment: Yes, but you can't stay in the old location forever, right? Your customers will eventually have to change to the new IP address(es).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thank you for the response.  You are correct, we can't stay forever but I was hoping to buy more time while we make a transition.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, thank you for the response.  One of the options was to delay updating DNS until later on after we had made the transition.  I already deployed a A/B test where our client software sends data to the current IP as well as the new IP.  We would keep the A/B test running until all customers could successfully connect to the new IP.  Is there a solution that doesn't include the overhead of VPN?  I was hoping to simply add a hop inline where Public IP1 gets forwarded to Public IP2, thus bypassing the IP block a customer might have on Public IP2.

Comment: I didn't post a full answer because I'm not confident enough that "there are no good solutions"; but you route a packet until it gets to its destination, but your current site *is* the destination - so you can't just add a route and send it further. And if you did forward the request to your new site, the return traffic would go to the client directly from the new site, which wouldn't work - the client is expecting the reply to come from your current IP. Without a VPN, could you reverse-proxy all connections through server(s) on your current site? Depends on your service design.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thanks, I didn't think to reverse proxy the connections.  I thought NAT might work but, reverse proxy is a better idea if we decide to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good answer for you as you will loose site A, and if you ask I assume your ISP can't give you the same IP on the new site.

The only thing that can *help* to keep you customer happy is to do a well-done Change Management process.

> Change management is an approach to transition individuals, teams, and
>   organizations to a desired future state.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_management) In a project management
>   context, change management may refer to a project management process
>   wherein changes to the scope of a project are formally introduced and
>   approved. From [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_management)

In such plan you usually state the change you need to do.

The approach is to contact your customer and do some communications; 3 general's step.

**The reason for the change**.

For yourself it's a move. Your customers will know that your enterprise will grow.

**Choosing what changes to implement**

Document yourself on what your customer might have to do.

- Changing firewall rule ?
- Proxy change ?

Document yourself on what you have to do.

- On day X, does the server rack will be ready for a fast move of the server and gear ?
- New IP already in hands ?

**Managing the change process**

From there you can start by contacting the new ISP to know the future IP address, as many customer can whitelist 2 IPs, thus the change on day X will be already's done.

**Conclusion**

In all that I wrote, the must important is to keep your customers informed, with the new IP you will have, the moving date & the new address

Comment: Thank you.  This is all perfectly reasonable and the direction we are taking.  Sadly, I live in a world where regardless of the change management process we use; customers will not do their part and blame us when things don't work.  I was trying to have a "magic" solution in order to deal with customers who are unable/unwilling to comply.